# Moderation: Interaction is not significant but sum of coefficients is significant

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have a simple model:
$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X + \beta_2 Y + \beta_3 XY+\epsilon$, where Y is a dummy variable.

I found that $\beta_1=-0.17, \beta_3=0.04$. While $\beta_1$ is statistically significant, $\beta_3$ is not. Then, I found out that $\beta_1+\beta_3=-0.13$ is also statistically insignificant. How should I interpret this? Should I just say that the interaction does not exist and the effect of X is -0.17 per unit? Or, should I clarify that for group Y, the effect of X is not significant despite the insignificance of $\beta_3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the [issue of statistical significance](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00857-9), I think you are making a slight misinterpretation:

> How should I interpret this? Should I just say that the interaction
> does not exist and the effect of X is -0.17 per unit?

You should be hesitant about concluding that 'the interaction does not exist' because the coefficient  [image]  is 'non-significant' for a few reasons. Firstly, your study may simply be underpowered to detect the interaction, as detecting interaction effects usually require much larger sample sizes than ordinary main effects. Secondly, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Not being able to disprove the null hypothesis (of no interaction), doesn't make it true. Thirdly, the estimate for the interaction is not zero. So saying that the overall slope of X is -0.17 is most likely incorrect, as it is based on the assumption that  [image]  = 0.

One simple way to represent the 'overall' effect of X without ignoring or removing the interaction is to recode your dummy variable Y. If Y is coded -0.5 for its low level and 0.5 for its high level, the coefficient [image] then comes to represent the mean effect of X, averaged over the two levels of Y.